# How to use uncompyle / uncompyle2

Tags: python

I've installed uncompyle (https://github.com/gstarnberger/uncompyle) but i'm not sure if i'm doing it right.  There's a directory in C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\uncompyle2 created, and I'd like to run this command.

Typing uncompyle -h is not helpful as well (though it was recommended based on the Readme document)

Comment: What about `uncompyle --help`? That should provide longer more helpful usage information.

Comment: The docs say `uncompyler --h`, not `uncompyle --h`. (And it looks like what actually gets installed requires `uncompyler.py -h` on POSIX, but on Windows you should be fine). If your problem is just that you don't know how to run the command, it's a simple typo; add the `r` to the end.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do that you need uncompyle for? Are you trying to teach yourself how Python bytecode works? Reverse engineer some .pyo module that a former contractor never delivered the source for before he got hit by a bus? At this point, you've got uncompyle working, but "it doesn't decompile since it's created using earlier version of python". What is the "it", what and why do you need it decompiled? (You may want to create a new question once you figure out what you want, because most people will ignore a question that's rated -2, and even more so if it keeps changing).

Answer (score 1):

You don't explain what you mean by "not helpful"—what exactly does it do? But I can guess that what it does is tell you there's no such program.

From the docs:

> Usage
>
> ---
>
> uncompyler -h     prints short usage
>
> uncompyler --help prints long usage

The problem is that you typed `uncompyle -h`, not `uncompyler -h`.

I don't have a Windows box handy to test on, but installing it on a Mac, I saw this:

```
    changing mode of /usr/local/bin/uncompyler.py to 755
```

On POSIX systems, you have to type `uncompyler.py -h` to test it (and the documentation should probably be fixed to reflect that). But on Windows, `uncompyler` and `uncompyler.py` basically mean the same thing.

So, assuming you let the Python installer put its bin/scripts directories on your path and set things up so that `.py` files are opened by Python, `uncompyler -h` will just work. Otherwise, you may have to type something like `C:\Python27\bin\Python C:\Python27\scripts\uncompyler -h`.

If I haven't guessed your actual problem, please clarify and I'll erase this answer.

Comment: Thanks guys.  I got this going through the following command:  c:\>python uncompyler.py myfile.pyc.  My problem now, it doesn't decompile since it's created using earlier version of python.. Any alternatives?

Comment: No. Uncompyler is explicitly written for Python 2.7 bytecode. While it _could_ be modified for, say, 2.6, that's unlikely to happen unless someone who knows Python internals suddenly runs into a need for it (or gets paid for it). So this avenue is probably a dead end for you. But if you tell us what you _actually_ want to do, there may be another avenue that makes more sense.